# NvTriStrip: Whats the licensing model, can I use it in my code?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, 3d, directx

I am planning to use NvTriStrip library for the software that will be licensed under a commercial license. It is okay to integrate NvTriStrip here?

I could not find a licensing agreement with NvTriStrip,

> http://www.nvidia.in/object/nvtristrip_library.html

Comment: You really need to ask Nvidia, or root around on their site. We don't have the inside scoop.